# Determine whether the given vectors are orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

Determine whether the given set of vectors are orthogonal?
$$S=\{ (1,0,-1),(0,3,-6),(0,2,-4) \}.$$
I just know that orthogonality of vectors in a vector space on case of symmetric bilinear form (also known as scalar product) is defined as follows:

$$B(e_i,e_j)=0$$ for $i\ne j$ where $${e_1,e_2,...,e_n}$$ is basis for V.

I guess the definition for $B$ here is $$B(x,y)=x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3$$ for $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ & $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$

Then should I check $$B(e_i,e_j)=0$$ for $i\ne j$ for $i,j=1,2,3$ ?
And if condition is satisfied for all cases then should I say the given set is orthogonal?

Comment: Yes, you should check this with $e_1 = (1,0,-1), e_2 = (0,3,-6),e_3 = (0,2,-4)$.

Comment: So I concluded the set is not orthogonal. Since for each case I am getting $$B\ne 0$$ Am i right?

Comment: Yes, that seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let the columns of $3 \times 3$ matrix $\rm V$ be the given vectors, i.e.,

$$\rm V := \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 3 & 2\\ -1 & -6 & -4\end{bmatrix}$$

Computing the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix), we obtain

$$\rm V^{\top} V = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 6 & 4\\ 6 & 45 & 30\\ 4 & 30 & 20\end{bmatrix}$$

What can we conclude, then?

Comment: since $V^TV \not=I$; $I$ is the identity matrix. So the column vectors of $V$ are not orthogonal.

Comment: That would be orthonormal.

Comment: I believe "not orthonormal" would  work for us. I think it will imply non-orthogonality.

Answer (score 0):

For first question: you don't need to do that. Since $B$ is symmetric, you only need to check three pairs.

For the second question: yes, by definition. So just do it.

---

"I guess the definition for $B$ here is..."

Don't guess. Check your book or ask your professor what is the definition of $B$. (In general, a symmetric bilinear form is not necessarily the standard inner product.) Otherwise this problem is undoable.